# Does this adverb fit the sentence?

Tags: phrase-usage

Does the adverb "for some moments" fit the sentence? Does the sentence make any sense?

> "I was scared to death for some moments, and then I realized that it is not a full-grown shark."

Comment: I think "a few moments" sounds better. I think it should be "it **was** not a full-grown shark."

Comment: Agree with @JMB on both points; I'd go with "for a minute" or "for a second" instead of "for some moments".  Or "for a moment".

Comment: I would use "some" for uncountable nouns like "for some time", but I agree with the other commenters that it should be "for a few moments" or "for a couple of moments" or even "for a moment" depending on how short you want his fear to be.

Comment: @JMB Depends on context, no? If you're talking about a shark that's still right next to you (e.g.. you're talking to your surfing buddy about the shark that just swam up to you) then "is" would be correct. If you're in a bar telling your buddy about the time you were out surfing and a shark swam up to you, then "was".

Comment: @AnthonyGrist Fair point, but I honestly think if any type/size of shark swam up next to me, I'd be right out of there! It would always be a past tense situation for me!

Comment: If you are telling this story after you are no longer in the situation, you should say "it WAS not ...". If you are still there, if you are talking to your diving buddy and the sea create in question is present, then you should say "it IS not ...".

Comment: "...for a moment..."

Answer (score 1):

I'd use *for a second*. And please don't forget that besides different forms of the verb *to be*, there is this very handy verb *to get* which is used a lot in daily English to mean that you were in a certain state of being for a short period of time.

Here's what I'd go with:

> I got pretty scared for a second, but then realized that it wasn't a full-grown shark.